# Java - get propertie names referenced from method

Tags: java, serialization, reflection, field, bytecode

So, I have this class:

```
public class Book {
private int id;
private String name;
private Something somebody;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Book book = (Book) o;

    if (id != book.id && somebody.getId() != book.somebody.getId()) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return id;
}
}
```

I would like to get all properties used in this class in equals method - in this case, I would get "id" from Book (since name is not used in equals method), and I would also get "somebody.id" since this is also used in equals method as sub object.

I need this info, so I can serialize only this properties and then during de-serialization on another machine use only that to compare equals. Otherwise it would be too cumbersome to compare full objects for equals (if I have too many sub-properties).

Comment: This is more trouble than it is worth. In any case, the requested task can be done using a bytecode manipulator library (this information is not available via normal reflection which cannot 'look into' methods or non-declaration code).. but not trivially, and with restrictions.

Comment: Side note: depending on the implementation used for serialization you can either use `transient` on fields not needed for serialization, or write a custom annotation to skip those fields programatically in your serialization implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Eclipse IDE, I know it has auto-complete options for `equals` and `hashcode` that will generate code including comparison of all declared fields. I am not sure if Netbeans or other IDEs have similar functionality, but would be surprised if commonly-used IDEs did not.

Also, your `equals` method should not compare fields of other objects but invoke `equals` on them:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if (this == o) return true;
   if (!(o instanceof Book)) return false; // instanceof is fast these days

   Book book = (Book) o;
   if (id == book.id &&
       // either ensure these are not null or use java.util.Objects.equals()
       somebody.equals(book.somebody))
      return true;

   return false;
}
```

Furthermore, if your hashcode is merely using `id` then perhaps your `equals` can as well. If your object is immutable, then `id` is all the comparison you would need, and would be quite a bit more efficient. If that is not the case, then it is typical that the checks used in `equals` are reflected in your `hashcode` to help prevent hash collisions.